# Conditional Operators in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, conditional-operator, comparison-operators

I am trying to compare two values from a label and textbox. When the AvailQty is at 6 it is considered to be "Low" and if a user types in 4 or 10 it will display error because there's only 6 available.

I have this:

```
if ((Int32.Parse(AvailQty.Text) <= 6) && (Int32.Parse(Qty.Text) > 6))
{
    lblAvailQty = "error";
}
```

This works but how can I make it so that if the user enters more than 6 or below 6 display error and do it in an efficient way because I feel like I am going to have a lot of if statements.

Comment: This is the default behaviour of `&&` operator. Rest of your question is not clear.

Comment: Please clarify your question. What does *make it fully stop and do the rest in an efficient way* mean?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I have reworded my question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, when the available quantity is less than or equal to 6 it should error. Also, if the requested quantity is greater than the available quantity, it should also error.

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
int avail = Int32.Parse(lblAvailQty.Text);
int req = Int32.Parse(txtQty.Text);

if (avail <= 6 || req > avail)
{
    //Display error
    //Do whatever else you need
}
```

Comment: You're a software developer and you "forget" about "or"?

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this inside of some event handler you can just put single "return;" operator inside the same if () {} block as the last operator.

It will effectively interrupt execution of the event handler.

Example:

```
if ((Int32.Parse(lblAvailQty.Text) <= 6) && (Int32.Parse(txtQty.Text) <= 6))
{
    lblAvailQty = "error";
    return;
}
```

Comment: This should have rather been a comment than an *answer*, don't you think?

Comment: Didn't I provide the solution? :O

Comment: Well, comes a bit short, imho ;)